# How does a recursive function work in javascript

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

When a function invokes itself does an identical copy of the function get created to be executed? and if that so is the execution of the original function get paused for the duplicate to run in a single-threaded language like javascript

```
function pow(x, n) {
  return (n == 1) ? x : (x * pow(x, n - 1));
}

pow(2, 3); //8
```

Comment: Add a `console.log(n)` before and after the call to `pow()` and at least the second question will be answered.

Comment: They key is that JavaScript maintains a bunch of *stack frames* which store context about the current function call. When a new function is called, it adds a new *frame* to the *stack*.

Comment: Please search your title before asking

Comment: Also see: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-the-javascript-call-stack-861e41ae61d4/ and https://felixgerschau.com/javascript-event-loop-call-stack/#call-stack